# html {{^Foo}} ^ selector tag

Tags: html, syntax, template-engine

I keep seeing this in an html code Im looking at. Apparently its Jquery tags to add html templates.

```
{{#Foo}} 
<div> bla bla </div>
```

I guess class Foo??

and

```
{{^Foo}}
<div> bla bla </div>
```

What is ^ for??

Now I know what it does, it stores HTML element in variable `Foo`, then these HTML elements get added later on. but I don't know how it works or why its # and ^ or anything more about what's going on here...

thank you for any help.

Im using html + javascript codes.

Comment: are you sure this is Jquery and not a template engine like handlebars or mustache?

Comment: This is not jQuery code. jQuery does not provide such placeholders like you mentioned, this has to be handlebars or mustache

Comment: @PastorBones I think he might refer [to the jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).

Answer (score 4):

It's actually not jQuery Template (as you suggest), but [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html) used here. This syntax...

```
{{#Foo}}
...something
{{/Foo}}
{{^Foo}}
...something
{{/Foo}}
```

... is used to cover both cases:

- when `Foo` collection is not empty, it will be templated with inner block of `{{#Foo}}` normal section:
- when `Foo` collection is empty, the template of so-called `inverted section` (set within `{{^Foo}}`) will be used instead:

Example from the documentation:

```
{{#repo}}
  <b>{{name}}</b>
{{/repo}}
{{^repo}}
  No repos :(
{{/repo}}
```

It's actually quite useful: we often need to provide a separate template for 'no items' case. Usually it's done with something like `{{#if... }} ... {{#else}}` blocks, but this injects logic in templates. Mustache provides an alternative - and quite elegant, may I say - approach to this.

Comment: could be handlebars as well...it has same/similar syntax.

Comment: I didn't use Handlebars, but I quicked through Google and found out that indeed inverted sections are used there as well. Can you guide me to their documentation? [This page](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) doesn't mention them, afaics.

Comment: Click on the mustache to get to the [mainpage](http://handlebarsjs.com/) where you can find the rest;)

Answer (score 1):

My friend.. you've got lot more to learn about **Handlebars** first.

Check these links:

http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/4/19/Demo-of-Handlebars-and-why-you-should-consider-a-templating-engine

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like jQuery syntax.

This does however look like most templating engines' syntax, such as [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), or [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This is neither HTML nor jQuery. It's used by template engines or other scripts to do some work based on codes they are able to recognize in the source code of the document (for example beginning and ending with double curly braces in your case).